# calling pyspark udf with multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The below UDF doesn't work - am I passing 2 columns in correctly & calling the function in the right way?

Thanks!!

```
def shield(x, y):
    if x == '':
       shield = y
    else:
       shield = x
    return shield

df3.withColumn("shield", shield(df3.custavp1, df3.custavp1))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the passing the arguments to the udf is incorrect.

The correct way is given below:

```
>>> ls
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> R = Row("A1", "A2")
>>> df = sc.parallelize([R(*r) for r in zip(*ls)]).toDF()
>>> df.show
<bound method DataFrame.show of DataFrame[A1: bigint, A2: bigint]>
>>> df.show()
+---+---+
| A1| A2|
+---+---+
|  1|  5|
|  2|  6|
|  3|  7|
|  4|  8|
+---+---+

>>> def foo(x,y):
...     if x%2 == 0:
...             return x
...     else:
...             return y
... 
>>> 
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> 
>>> custom_udf = udf(foo, IntegerType())
>>> df1 = df.withColumn("res", custom_udf(col("A1"), col("A2")))
>>> df1.show()
+---+---+---+
| A1| A2|res|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  5|  5|
|  2|  6|  2|
|  3|  7|  7|
|  4|  8|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hmm, the script runs for a long time and then spits out this error. If I remove the UDF, the whole script runs so I don't really understand

Error from python worker:
  /usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark
PYTHONPATH was:
  /data3/yarn/local/filecache/10/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz/spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292.jar
java.io.EOFException

Comment: Are you using jupyter notebook?

Comment: No I am using straight in terminal. It is 100% linked to the UDF which now follows your guidelines, but still creates the error. When I remove the line, it does not error